# Docker run works fine but in docker compose it fails

Tags: docker, apache-spark

```
version: '3'

services:

  spark-master:

    image: apache/spark-py:latest`
```

I am trying to build a container with apache spark image (mainly trying to run apache spark with airflow in a single project). Docker run works fine for pulled apache/spark-py:latest image but when I put this in docker-compose as service, it fails with some error.

" Execute a program under the supervision of a valid init process (tini)"

what to do ??

But when I run

```
docker run -it apache/spark-py:latest
```

it runs container fine. I am confused !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1. this command does not work fine

i run this to start a container,

`docker run -it apache/spark-py:latest`

use `docker ps -a`, and found the container status is **Exited**

So this shows that the container should be started in interactive mode and enter the bash terminal.

change the command to the below, and it worked fine.

`docker run -it apache/spark-py:latest /bin/bash`

##### 2. in docker-compose.yml

I suggest you replace the image with this:

```
image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3
```

and start docker-compose.yml again. It worked fine on my server.

---

if you insist on using the image: `apache/spark-py:latest`, you should add a command in your docker-compose.yml that makes the command to resident foreground process after it'd execute,such as:

```
command: tail -f /tmp/java_opts.txt
```

Comment: This works, thanks. what this does exactly "command: tail -f /tmp/java_opts.txt" ?

Comment: and bitnami image responds too slow when i use it though i have enough resources for docker .

Comment: **1.** This command is to ensure that in your container, the command executs in the background instead of exiting after it's execution. of course, you can replace it with other spark-related commands. **2.** It may be your network problem, maybe using vpn will make some help